# Subcaption label on the top and center

Tags: subcaption

```
\begin{table}[H]
\tiny
\subfloat[A]{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
g1 & g2  & ex & Error Rate\\
\hline

0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.331\\

0.001 & 0.001 & 0.01  & 0.336 \\

0.001 & 0.001 & 0.1   & 0.333\\

0.001 & 0.01 & 0.001  & 0.331\\

0.001 & 0.01 & 0.01   & 0.336\\

0.001 & 0.01 & 0.1    & 0.333\\

\end{tabular}}
\qquad
\subfloat[B]{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}

g1 & g2  & ex & Error Rate\\

\hline

0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.246\\

0.001 & 0.001 & 0.01  & 0.220 \\


\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.sx. I added syntax highlighting to your code by selecting it and clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, `position=top` is what you need. You can add `\captionsetup{position=top}` inside the `table` to apply it for a single table, or you can add `\captionsetup[subtable]{position=top}` to the preamble to apply it for all subtables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subtable]{position=top}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\tiny
%\captionsetup{position=top} % to apply it for a single table
\subfloat[A]{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
g1 & g2  & ex & Error Rate\\
\hline
0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.331\\
0.001 & 0.001 & 0.01  & 0.336 \\
0.001 & 0.001 & 0.1   & 0.333\\
0.001 & 0.01 & 0.001  & 0.331\\
0.001 & 0.01 & 0.01   & 0.336\\
0.001 & 0.01 & 0.1    & 0.333\\
\end{tabular}}
\qquad
\subfloat[B]{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
g1 & g2  & ex & Error Rate\\
\hline
0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.246\\
0.001 & 0.001 & 0.01  & 0.220 \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```